# SwiftUI Transitions have different implementation?

Tags: swiftui, transition, swiftui-animation

I have been testing how transitions work based on [SwiftUI-labs](https://swiftui-lab.com/advanced-transitions/) but I found that transitions should not all be implemented in the same way.
Based on the previous article:

> Note that since XCode 11.2, transitions no longer work with implicit
>   animations

Thing is, that I found something strange. Some transitions work fine when using either implicit animation OR by associating an animation to it. So, what animation should be used? Well, it depends. On what? I don't know. I'm hoping anyone can help me explaining all this.

In the following test, I have created 5 views, each one associated with a different transition: `.opacity`,`.scale`, `.move`, `.slide`, and `combined`(`.opacity` and `.move`). Here are my findings:

NOTE: I'M USING XCODE 11.4 AND THE SIMULATOR!

**Transitions using implicit animation**

Only `.move` and `.slide` transitions work OK (removal and insertion).

[image]

**Transitions using explicit animation**

Removal and insertion animation works OK for all transitions.

[image]

**Associating an animation to each transition**

Only `.scale` and `.opacity` transitions work OK (removal and insertion).

[image]

From my point of view, not having a standard way of implementing transitions complicates things, moreover when combining transitions (`.combined`).

Am I missing something about the implementation? Here's my code:

```
struct TestAnimation: View {
    @State var show : Bool = true
    var colors : [Color] = [.orange, .yellow, .green, .blue, .pink]

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Spacer()

            Color.purple
                .frame(height: 100)
                .overlay(
                    Text("Tap Me!").foregroundColor(.white))
                .onTapGesture {
                    // (#1) implicit animation
                    self.show.toggle()

                    // (#2) explicit animation
                    /*withAnimation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 1)) {
                        self.show.toggle()
                    }*/

                    // (#3) associate an animation with a transition
                    //self.show.toggle()
            }

            HStack {
                if show {
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(colors[0])
                        .frame(width: 70, height: 100)
                        .overlay(Text("opacity"))
                        .transition(AnyTransition.opacity) // (#1) - doesn't animate, only removes/inserts the view
                        .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1)) // (#1) 
                        //.transition(AnyTransition.opacity) // (#2) - only animates the removal, not the insertion
                        //.transition(AnyTransition.opacity.animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1))) // (#3) - animates removal and insertion

                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(colors[1])
                        .frame(width: 70, height: 100)
                        .overlay(Text("scale"))
                        .transition(AnyTransition.scale) // (#1) - doesn't animate, only removes/inserts the view
                        .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1)) // (#1) 
                        //.transition(AnyTransition.scale) // (#2) - only animates the removal, not the insertion
                        //.transition(AnyTransition.scale.animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1))) // (#3) - animates removal and insertion

                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(colors[2])
                        .frame(width: 70, height: 100)
                        .overlay(Text("move"))
                        .transition(AnyTransition.move(edge: .bottom)) // (#1) - animates removal and insertion
                        .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1)) // (#1) 
                        //.transition(AnyTransition.move(edge: .bottom)) // (#2) - only animates the removal, not the insertion
                        //.transition(AnyTransition.move(edge: .bottom).animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1))) // (#3) - doesn't animate, only removes/inserts the view

                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(colors[3])
                        .frame(width: 70, height: 100)
                        .overlay(Text("slide"))
                        .transition(AnyTransition.slide) // (#1) - animates removal and insertion
                        .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1)) // (#1) 
                        //.transition(AnyTransition.slide) // (#2) - only animates the removal, not the insertion
                        //.transition(AnyTransition.slide.animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1))) // (#3) - doesn't animate, only removes/inserts the view

                    Rectangle()
                    .fill(colors[4])
                    .frame(width: 70, height: 100)
                    .overlay(Text("op&mv"))
                    .transition(AnyTransition.opacity.combined(with: .move(edge: .bottom))) // (#1) - doesn't animate, only removes/inserts the view
                    .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1)) // (#1) 
                    //.transition(AnyTransition.opacity.combined(with: .move(edge: .bottom))) // (#2) - only animates removal, not the insertion
                        //.transition(AnyTransition.opacity.combined(with: .move(edge: .bottom)).animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1))) // (#3) - animates removal (it's not smooth), and only animates opacity on insertion
                }
            }
            .frame(height: 100)
            .padding(7)
                .border(Color.gray)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I would add that Preview does not always renders transitions (or not all) properly, so retest everything at least on Simulator.

Comment: I like the thoroughness of your tests.  Preview is just generally weak. It seems so not ready for prime-time.

Comment: @Asperi, I have tested everything in the simulator. The only difference is when using explicit animations: all transitions work as expected. But still, the question remains, why there's a different behavior for transitions when using implicit OR when associating an animation to it?

Comment: @HalR I have generated new gifs using the simulator this time.

Comment: If I put the testAnimation into another view and animate it every version works fine. `    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TestAnimation()
        }.animation(.easeInOut)
    }` Just btw.

Comment: Mate I just noticed this and thought there was something I wasn't understanding. `.opacity` animated fine with transition associated with animation but `.move` did not. I had to add an animation modifier to get `.move` to work - so weird

Comment: @HalR yep that works, that must mean it's a bug in SwiftUI then?